# VUE - FIREBASE | How to get the user profile from the realtime database

Tags: firebase, vue.js, firebase-realtime-database

I got the user profile from the Realtime database but when I have more than 1 account I get the second user profile too.

Here below you see the data from 2 users. But I want to get the user that is loggend in and that is the  **currentUser**

The ID is the **currentUser**

[image]

This is the Realtime database:

[image]

This is my **Profile.vue page**:

```
          <div class="container" v-for="profileData of profile" :key="profileData['.key']">
            <div v-if="seen" class="row">
              <div class="col">
                <div class="card card-border" style="width: 30rem;">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title text-center mb-4">Personal information</h4>
                      <p class="card-text">ID: {{profileData.CurrentUser}}</p>
                      <p class="card-text">First name: {{profileData.firstName}}</p>
                      <p class="card-text">Last name: {{profileData.lastName}}</p>
                      <p class="card-text">Phone number: {{profileData.phoneNumber}}</p>
                      <p class="card-text">Adress: {{profileData.adress}}</p>
                      <p class="card-text">Citizenship: {{profileData.citizenship}}</p>
                      <p class="card-text">Personal email: {{profileData.personalEmail}}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="col"></div>
              <div class="col">
                <div class="card card-border" style="width: 30rem;">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title text-center mb-3">Business information</h4>
                      <p>Company name: {{profileData.companyName}}</p>
                      <p>Chamber Of Commerce Number: {{profileData.chamberOfCommerceNumber}}</p>
                      <p>Street: {{profileData.street}}</p>
                      <p>House number: {{profileData.houseNumber}}</p>
                      <p>ZIP code: {{profileData.zipCode}}</p>
                      <p>Location: {{profileData.location}}</p>
                      <p>Company email: {{profileData.companyEmail}}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

I added a if/else in the **created()** section below.

And this is the script:

```
<script>
import firebase from "firebase";
import { db } from '../../config/db';

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: "",
      profileData: [],
      isHidden: true,
      seen: true,
      isLoggedIn: false
    }
  },
  firebase: {
    profile: db.ref('profile')
  },
  methods: {
    resetPassword() {
      const auth = firebase.auth();
      auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(auth.currentUser.email).then(() => {
        console.log('Email send');
        // Email sent.
      }).catch((error) => {
        // An error happened.
        console.log(error);
      });
    }
  },
  created() {
    if(firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      this.isLoggedIn = true;
      this.currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
    }
    var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    if (this.user == this.profileData.CurrentUser) {
      this.seen = true;
    } else {
      this.seen = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

In this Profile.vue page I have the **add function**:

```
AddProfile() {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(this.profileData) + this.currentUser)
            this.$firebaseRefs.profile.push({
                firstName: this.profileData.firstName,
                lastName: this.profileData.lastName,
                phoneNumber: this.profileData.phoneNumber,
                adress: this.profileData.adress,
                citizenship: this.profileData.citizenship,
                personalEmail: this.profileData.personalEmail,
                companyName: this.profileData.companyName,
                chamberOfCommerceNumber: this.profileData.chamberOfCommerceNumber,
                street: this.profileData.street,
                houseNumber: this.profileData.houseNumber,
                zipCode: this.profileData.zipCode,
                location: this.profileData.location,
                companyEmail: this.profileData.companyEmail,
                CurrentUser: this.currentUser
            })
            this.profileData.firstName = '';
            this.profileData.lastName = '';
            this.profileData.phoneNumber = '';
            this.profileData.adress = '';
            this.profileData.personalEmail = '';
            this.profileData.companyName = '';
            this.profileData.chamberOfCommerceNumber = '';
            this.profileData.street = '';
            this.profileData.houseNumber = '';
            this.profileData.zipCode = '';
            this.profileData.location = '';
            this.profileData.companyEmail = '';
            this.CurrentUser = '';
            window.scrollTo(0,0, 0,0);
            console.log('Added to database');
            /* Waiting for 2 seconds here */
            this.$router.push('/internship')
        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you are using [Vuefire](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/).

As you will see in the Vuefire documentation, by doing

```
firebase: {
  profile: db.ref('profile')
},
```

you are using a [declarative biding](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#declarative-binding) on the `profile` Realtime Database node and therefore **it is normal that you get all the children of this node**.

---

If you just want to display the node corresponding to the current user, you could use the [programmatic binding](https://vuefire.vuejs.org/vuefire/binding-subscriptions.html#programmatic-binding), along the following lines:

```
<template>
  <div class="home">
    {{user}}
    <ol></ol>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { db } from "../firebase";
const profile = db.ref("profile");
export default {
  name: "demo",
  data() {
    return {
      user: null,
      id: null
    };
  },
  watch: {
    id: {
      immediate: true,
      handler(id) {
        this.$rtdbBind("user", profile.child(id));
      }
    }
  },
  created() {

    if (firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      this.id = currentUser.uid;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got this error: Error: Reference.child failed: First argument was an invalid path = "null". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".", "#", "$", "[", or "]". I want to check if the currentUser equal is with the CurrentUser in the Realtime database an d take only that part of the information.

Comment: You need to be authenticated to open this component, since you fetch for a node corresponding to the user uid.

Comment: You cloud check in the handler if `id` is null or not.